# Pisano period generator behaves incorrectly for 3-digit periods

Tags: c++

I have a C++ code which is supposed to return the Pisano period value for any value m. The code works correctly when the period is 2-digited, but generates incorrect values for 3-digited periods. Eg:- Period(24) = 24 which is correctly generated
Period(25) = 1243 (which is INCORRECT , it should be = 100)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long long m;
    cin >> m;
    long period = 1;
    long prev1 = 0;
    long cur1 = 1;
    long long prev2 = 0;
    long long cur2 = 1;
    while (1)
    {
        long long tmp = prev2;
        prev2 = cur2;
        cur2 = tmp + prev2;
        period = period + 1;
        if (((cur2 % m) == prev1) && (((cur2 + prev2) % m) == cur1))
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << period;
}
```

Comment: You only care about the Fibonacci numbers modulo `m`, so you can calculate them modulo `m` inside the loop, instead of letting them grow arbitrarily large. This will solve your overflow problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compute the next fibonacci number, you do :

```
    long long tmp = prev2;
    prev2 = cur2;
    cur2 = tmp + prev2;
    period = period + 1;
```

There's nothing in there to prevent overflow. Even `long long` eventually overflow. You should try keeping only the modulo part of `prev2` and `cur2` to avoid the overflow.

I don't have quite enough number theory knowledge to guarantee you it will work, but it looks plausible.